# How to add more than 4 build " independent commands " in Geany text editor? (inside Build > Set Build Commands)

Tags: build, geany

In geany text editor we can add our custom commands under BUILD menu.

For example, to reformat the c-program source codes i did this:

Build > Set Build Commands > Independent command

```
Label = Reformat C code  
Command = astyle -A1 -Y %f  
Working directory = %d
```

Now, my question is can how to add more independent build commands?
There are only four labels and 3 of which are already occupied, I also 
read the manuals of geany text editor, but it didn't help.

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!
Some useful links are following:
http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#set-build-commands
http://wiki.geany.org/howtos/configurebuildmenu

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add more by adjusting

```
number_ft_menu_items=0
number_non_ft_menu_items=0
number_exec_menu_items=0
```

The default is 0 = default settings = 4 for number_non_ft_menu_items. 
You can set these via config file (don't open it with Geany as it will be overwritten during close down) or Edit -> Preferences -> Various. Please check [manual](http://www.geany.org/manual/current/#various-preferences) for details.